# How to get all elements from an API call

Tags: c#

I have downloaded some prewritten code that helps me make an API call. The API call gets all end-day stockprices for at time period of my choice.

The problem is that i can only get the stockprice from the latest date to show in the program.

How can i write this code to get alla elements inside the "StockPricesList"?

```
static void StockPricesForAllInstruments()
{
    ApiClient api = new ApiClient(_apiKey);
    InstrumentRespV1 inst = api.GetInstruments();

    foreach (var i in inst.Instruments)
    {
        StockPricesRespV1 sp = api.GetStockPrices(i.InsId.Value, Convert.ToDateTime("2012-01-01"), DateTime.Today);  

        StockPriceV1 Kurs = sp.StockPricesList.Last();
        Console.WriteLine(Kurs.C);
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you change `StockPriceV1 Kurs = sp.StockPricesList.Last();` to `var Kurs = sp.StockPricesList;` and change `Console.WriteLine(Kurs.C);` to `foreach (var price in Kurs) { Console.WriteLine(price.C); }`. Also it would help if you link the library you're using.

Comment: `StockPriceV1 Kurs = sp.StockPricesList.Last();` you are getting only the last element here. Just remove `.Last()` and you will have a list.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
var Kurs = sp.StockPricesList.Last();
```

with

```
var Kurs = sp.StockPricesList.ToList();

foreach (StockPriceV1 kur in Kurs)
{
Console.WriteLine(kur.C);
}
```